# using inline css - a no-no or okay in certain situations?

Tags: html, css, class, stylesheet, inline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline styles vs styles in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721997/inline-styles-vs-styles-in-css)

i guess i'm looking for some opinions on this. I am all for using css styles as classes in a separate .css file. But every once in a while, i run into a scenario where i need just some padding for a particular element or change the css class' width only in one particular situation. Is it okay to add inline styles in those scenarios? do people do this or always create classes for everything.

My theory would be if its not something reusable or does not contain more than 2 styles, why create a class for it. Am I wrong in thinking that?

**Summary of Answers** (since there are many)

It is better to avoid inline styles because

1) style sheets provides more maintainability.

2) better separation of html data and layout.

3) re-usability of styles.

4) probably provides better caching.

Overall, css style sheet is the best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two answers to this one:

**1)** It's considered good practice to keep your design (css) and your data (html) separate.  By adding in-line styles, it makes it more difficult to revise the look of a site, it makes it more difficult for future programmers to modify your site, and is overall NOT the best way to go.

If everything is in a CSS file(s), then you can change the entire design of your site without having to mess with the data (HTML) of the site.  This is ideal.

**2)**  Yes, a lot of people still use inline styles very often when tweaking something small, regardless of "best practice".

Comment: everyone had good comments and its tough to accept a single answer. However, I think you summarized it (slightly) better than the best ones.

Comment: @coder net - glad to help (and I that all good comments)

Answer (score 6):

Anything is reusable if you think it through and set it up correctly.  Even one-line, one element CSS attributes can be beneficial if reused.  This takes advantage of the concept of caching, which will keep the css in memory after the initial load hit.  No matter which way you slice it, inline styles add to your overhead every load without question.

Never mind the fact that inline mixed with a proper css document adds overhead to your own debug time, figuring out where the darned calls are coming from.

Comment: just out of curiosity, i have run into situations where a div element has a class with lets say some padding right value. Only in one situation, it needs to have some extra padding than what the class provides. How do you handle this? add another class?

Comment: @coder net: In a case like this, you can add an ID or a second class (`class="class1 class2"`) to the div.

Comment: i agree. This is what i have been doing too in the past, but it seemed like an overhead to me to add a new css class just for a tweak. I suppose it is okay to have more classes in css file as the benefits far outweigh the other.

Comment: This is wrong. inline styles are the best practice in some cases where the style are generated via server-side, they contain user-defined styles and are applied to only one single element, insert such styles in a separated file will create only problems. more details at https://forums.envato.com/t/wrong-and-dangerous-review-requirement-for-wordpress-themes-and-wordpress-and-php-plugins/374407

Comment: @FedericoSchiocchet take a close look at the date this was written.....lots has changed in 10 years....

Answer (score 3):

You said: "if its not something reusable or does not contain more than 2 styles"

I would add another reason to use external stylesheets: maintainability. If you (or someone else) has to fix your code in the future, you will have a much easier time of it if all of your styling is in one place. You will not remember that you added that little bit of styling inline, and you may spend hours hunting for it.

It is a good standard to keep all styling separate to maintain clean, maintainable code.

That said, we can acknowledge that it is "ok" to use inline styles, as you asked in your question. However, *best practice* is often something more than "ok" and should serve as a guide as often as possible.

Comment: As many points out, I totally agree with the maintainability factor.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like a good balance is all that you need. While its typically considered better practice to create classes as much as possible, there comes a point when its just easier to use an inline style. Like you said, if there's just that one element that needs that minimal extra padding, its not a crime to give it that. At least, in my opinion it isn't. But definitely be in the habit of making classes for just about everything, except minor exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Its not just about re-use, its about getting into the habit of doing things correctly. What if someone else needed to help you on the project, they would have to sift through your whole file to find every instance of an inline style somewhere...

People who know their CSS always create a specific style rule for everything.

Thats my opinion and I believe it to be shared among my colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

A big point for me is: maintenance. When all of the CSS is in external stylesheets, it is going to be relatively straightforward to find the styles your looking for to edit them. If there are inline styles, it will be harder to find what you're looking for.

I'm usually skeptical about claims that a style never be reused. If it happened once, it is likely to happen again. Coding for reusability is always a good idea and usually results in cleaner, better written code in my experience.

Even in these situations, I will usually add a unique class somewhere up in the target element's ancestors - often on the body tag - that I can use to target the the "unique situation" and keep all the CSS in the external stylesheet.

That being said, I do occasionally use inline styles. When I do, it is almost exclusively in a situation where I know that I will be animating styles with JavaScript after the page has loaded. I only do inline styles for the properties that I am going to animate and the rest go in the external stylesheet.