# remove space between lines, single page only

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the extra space between lines, but only for this part.  Not on any other page.  Basically I want the line starting with -- to appear directly under the text above it.  I do need the padding for the tag to remain as well.  I'm guessing this would be done via a class id, but not sure of the css code that I would use.  Margin?  Something along the lines of

```
<h3 class="removeSpace">
```

**HTML**

```
<h3><em>Some text here</em></h3><h3> – blah blah blah</h3>
<h3><em>Other text here</em></h3><h3> – yadda yadda yadda</h3>
<h3><em>More text here</em></h3><h3> – blah blah blah</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
h3 {
    color: #7093DB;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Just put a break in you h3? And then set the line height to e.g. 0.9em

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it kind of similar to what you have, you can do this.  There's no need to have two `<h3>`'s in there.

```css
h3 {
    color: #7093DB;
    padding-left: 300px;
}

h3 em {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3><em>Some text here</em> – blah blah blah</h3>
<h3><em>Other text here</em> – yadda yadda yadda</h3>
<h3><em>More text here</em> – blah blah blah</h3>
```

Comment: This seems the easiest of all answers and works perfectly.  Thanks!!

Comment: @BradAnderson LOOL apparently you didnt read read my answer at all

Comment: @dippas I read every answer.  Strictly guessing, your answer may not have been edited at the time I found the one from adpro.  Next time I will leave a comment immediately instead of taking the time to get my page working correctly first.  I appreciate everyone's help, the questions I have asked have assisted me in understanding things a bit better.

Comment: @BradAnderson, thank you. They're both very similar answers, but yes, mine existed before his edit. It still feels odd to me to make an inline element a block element, but it seems, after looking into it a bit further, it's acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `span` inside `h3` for that and set it `display:block` and avoid all that extra markup

```css
h3 {
  color: #7093DB;
  padding-left: 300px;
}

h3 span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<h3><em>Some text here </em> <span>– blah blah blah</span></h3>
<h3><em>Some text here </em> <span>– blah blah blah</span></h3>
<h3><em>Some text here </em> <span>– blah blah blah</span></h3>
```

Even **LESS** MARKUP just set `display:block` in `em`

```css
h3 {
  color: #7093DB;
  padding-left: 300px;
}

h3 em {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<h3><em>Some text here </em> – blah blah blah</h3>
<h3><em>Some text here </em> – blah blah blah</h3>
<h3><em>Some text here </em> – blah blah blah</h3>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer now.

Comment: I have 2 options, in my answer,  so no, not the same as your answer

Comment: Ah, I missed the other code snippet.  The only one displaying is the same as mine.  But thanks for taking my answer and adding it to yours, haha.  I also added another answer.  You can add two.  I think there's benefit in not turning inline elemnts into blocks.

Comment: for the part of inline into block read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853141/is-changing-default-display-property-a-good-practice/37908116#37908116)

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with `margin`
Might be cleaner to do this another way with div wrappers and spans, but if you want to change the h3 tags you can do it like this:

```css
h3 {
    color: #7093DB;
    padding-left: 300px;
}

.removespace {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="removespace"><em>Some text here</em></h3><h3 class="child"> – blah blah blah</h3>
<h3 class="removespace"><em>Other text here</em></h3><h3 class="child"> – yadda yadda yadda</h3>
<h3 class="removespace"><em>More text here</em></h3><h3 class="child"> – blah blah blah</h3>
```

Comment: I agree. Your answer with the spans would be much better

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a reusable class (IDs have little practical use in CSS) which you can apply as you like:

```
h3.snug {
    margin: 0;
}

<h3 class="snug"> ... </h3>
```

Alternatively, apply a class to a wrapper element on the page:

```
.snug h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

<div class="snug">
    <h3> ... </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of this depends on what content you are displaying.  Since you said it won't be the same everywhere, I've added a class, and added sections.  If this is kind of its own section you could just wrap it all in a section.  You could also throw a `div` with a class container or something like that as well for the padding.  I would assume you probably have more HTML on the page, so something else might make more sense.  I've also added a `<p>` tag, because "css purests" might not be cool with turning those inline elements into block elements.

So, here's a solution that has some other benefits, depending on what your specific needs are.  This is more HTML5 friendly.

```css
section.some-section {
    padding-left: 300px;
}

section.some-section h3 {
    color: #7093DB;
}

section.some-section p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-section">
    <h3><em>Some text here</em> <p>– blah blah blah</p></h3>
</section>

<section class="some-section">
    <h3><em>Other text here</em> <p>– yadda yadda yadda</p></h3>
</section>

<section class="some-section">
    <h3><em>More text here</em> <p>– blah blah blah</p></h3>
</section>
```